# Adding settings to Sublime.settings file

Tags: settings, sublimetext3

I'm adding a Slack integration to my Sublime3 setup. This is the first time I'm doing this kind of customization.

My base Sublime.settings file is:

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Installed packages",
        "Animate.css Snippets",
        "Package Control",
        "Slack" //there are otherrs
    ]
 }
```

This was working fine. When I added:

```
{
    "team_tokens": {
        "Team 1": "Token 1",
        "Team 2": "Token 2",
        "Team 3": "Token 3"
    },
    "username": "myName",
    "username_subtext": "via Sublime",
    "show_plaform_and_name": true,
    "repeat_file_ext": false,
    "avatar_url": "http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/icons/icon.png"
}
```

I got the following error message when I attempted to save. "Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings:19:1", where in the base file, line 19 position 1 is the start of the first parentheses of the additional code.

I think the problem is with the formatting, but I'm not finding the problem. Any insight?

Comment: You edit the wrong file (`Package Control.sublime-settings` is for configuring Package Control, not Sublime in general). The error message tells you what you need to know; you broke the file at line 19. Hard to say exactly how since you don't provide the full file, but make sure that all entries are comma separated and you didn't add an extra object structure on the end. http://jsonlint.com/ might help you track where it's breaking.

Comment: As @OdatNurd said you should open the settings via the menu *Preferences >> Settings* and use the settings on the right side. Based on our description I assume that you just appended instead of join both code blocks, which does not work. You should put the content of the second braces into the braces of the first block instead and ensure, that the key, value pairs are comma separated.

Comment: Thank you for helping out a newbie, OdaNurd and @r-stein. That cleared things up. 

I dropped the Slack integration settings within the outer parentheses and eliminated one et of inner parentheses in the Preferences.sublime-settings – user file. Working now. [instructions I was attempting to follow](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Slack).